# Ckeditor sends default content

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I use ckeditor with a default content. Then I initialize (replace textarea) CKEditor with jquery and I edit the text.
The problem is that var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val(); returns default content and also getData().
What I have to do to grab the actual content?
Thank you very much

```
var ed = $( '#ed' ).ckeditor(
      {toolbar :[
                 { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic' ] },
                 {name: 'link', items:['Link']},    
                 { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor' ] }
                ]
       }
      );
```

Comment: can you please provide some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the developers guide: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

You need to make sure that your jQueryAdapter script is included *after* the ckeditor script.

> In order to create editor instances, load the usual CKEditor core script file as well as the jQuery Adapter file, in the following order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```